# How to use txtbox.DataBindings with foreign table's attribute?

Tags: c#, data-binding, ms-access-2016

I have a listbox that displays Vacancy.Description

```
lstBoxVacancy.DataSource = DM.lookingGlassDS;                                               
lstBoxVacancy.DisplayMember = "Vacancy.Description";                                        
lstBoxVacancy.ValueMember = "Vacancy.Description";
```

[Listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h0Uq.png)

When you click on one of the items in the listbox, the text boxes on the side correlate to the selected description row(Vacancy.Description).

[Listbox with associated textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z45k.png)

```
txtVacancyID.DataBindings.Add("Text", DM.lookingGlassDS, "Vacancy.VacancyID");   
txtDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", DM.lookingGlassDS, "Vacancy.Description"); 
txtStatus.DataBindings.Add("Text", DM.lookingGlassDS, "Vacancy.Status");  
txtSalary.DataBindings.Add("Text", DM.lookingGlassDS, "Vacancy.Salary"); 
txtVacancyEmployerID.DataBindings.Add("Text", DM.lookingGlassDS, "Vacancy.EmployerID");
txtVacancyEmployerName.DataBindings.Add("Text", DM.lookingGlassDS, "Employer.EmployerName");
```

However, for the EmployerName value, the "Employer Name:" textbox is not changing when you select a new item in the listbox. I think this is because EmployerName comes from the Employer table and not the Vacancy table like the rest of the DataBindings.

```
txtVacancyEmployerName.DataBindings.Add("Text", DM.lookingGlassDS, "Employer.EmployerName");
```

My question is how do I make it so that when I click on a listbox item (Vacancy.Description), the associated EmployerName(Employer.EmployerName) is displayed in the EmployerName textbox?

In my DataSet, it says the relation name is EMPLOYERVACANCY between the Employer and Vacancy table. Parent table: EMPLOYER. Child table: VACANCY
Primary key: EmployerID, Forgein key:EmployerID

Thank you very much